# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bufferToHex') - Metamask

Tags: javascript, metamask

I am trying to encrypt a message by using a method from the Metamask RPC API ([here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#unrestricted-methods)).  I first use 'eth_getEncryptionPublicKey' to get the encryption key for the account that I am connected to.  I then use the following code to encrypt my message.  However, I am getting the following error and I do not understand how to address it.  Please can someone advise?

I do not know if this has anything to do with my errors but '@metamask/eth-sig-util' is written in TypeScript.

```
import ethUtil from 'ethereumjs-util';
import sigUtil from '@metamask/eth-sig-util';

const encryptString = (encryptionKey, text) => {
console.log('encryptString.encryptionKey: ' + encryptionKey);
console.log('encryptString.text: ' + text);

const encryptedMessage = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
  Buffer.from(
    JSON.stringify(
      sigUtil.encrypt({
        publicKey: encryptionKey,
        data: text,
        version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
      })
    ),
    'utf-8'
  )
);
```

};

console:

```
encryptString.publicKey: Rb1/QuAkQ7qpyo9wzY5+E0Kw2AkL1Vipb8LObOGkkNw=
encryptString.text: Hello World
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bufferToHex')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, using these imports worked for me:

```
import { bufferToHex } from 'ethereumjs-util';
import { encrypt } from '@metamask/eth-sig-util';
```

Full code adapted for your case:

```
import { bufferToHex } from 'ethereumjs-util';
import { encrypt } from '@metamask/eth-sig-util';

const encryptedMessage = bufferToHex(
    Buffer.from(
        JSON.stringify(
            encrypt({
                publicKey: encryptionKey,
                data: 'hello world!',
                version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
            }),
        ),
        'utf8',
    ),
);

console.log(`Encrypted message: ${encryptedMessage}`);

const decryptedMessage = await window as.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_decrypt',
    params: [encryptedMessage, account],
});

console.log(`Decrypted message: ${decryptedMessage}`);
```

[image]